# Switching between previewing personalization options in Sitecore causes display issues in PageEditor

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7, sitecore-dms

On a project that I'm working on we've implemented DMS functionality and some of the components that we're added personalization too are quite interactive and JQuery heavy.

When our content editors switch between the Personalized versions of components in PageEditor it's resulting in a bit of a mess.

This appears to be due to the fact that the JQuery events and so on need to be reapplied to the altered elements on the page.  I can't find any documentation on this particular piece of functionality, are there any events that can be hooked into on this? Failing that are there any other workarounds?

Comment: Could you give an example of an event that won't fire? An obvious thought here is to bind live events so they fire as and when the DOM is manipulated.

Answer (score 0):

My method for including javascript on renderings seems to work in this situation. We use require.js to define all the dependencies and then each rendering requires in the js files and initializes itself.

Example Razor code for the rendering

```
<div class="slider"><!-- Slider HTML --></div>
<script>
require(["jquery", "sliderjs"], function($, slider) {
    // Initialize your slider here
});
</script>
```

This works because the script tag is executed as the html is appended to the DOM and then require takes over loading in the javascript files that are required by the module and then it runs the function. We don't need to use the jQuery document ready function.